# Trying to delete an element from a double linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list, double

Ι have a problem while trying to delete an element from a double linked list in c.

```
Nodes_t *remove_Nodes (Nodes_t *a, Nodes_t b){
    Nodes_t *head;
    head=a;
    if ((a->i_pos==b.i_pos) && (a->j_pos==b.j_pos)){
        if (a->next=NULL){
            return NULL;
            }
        else {
            head=a->next;
            head->previous=NULL;
            return head;
            }
        }
    else if ((a->i_pos!=b.i_pos) || (a->j_pos!=b.j_pos)){
        while ((a->next->i_pos!=b.i_pos)||(a->next->j_pos!=b.j_pos)){
            a=a->next;
            if (a->next=NULL){
                return head;
                }
            }
        a=a->next;
        a->previous->next=a->next;
        if (a->next=NULL){
            return head;
            }
        else if (a->next!=NULL){
            a->next->previous=a->previous;
            return head;
            }               
        }
        return head;        
    }
```

It gets a double linked list, finds an element of type Nodes_t and then deletes it.
Although, as I have checked the list and its pointers work fine, when I try to call the function to delete my first element I get a seg fault.

More specifically, as I have checked, the function proceeds just fine until it gets  to this point

```
else {
            head=a->next;
            head->previous=NULL;// HERE 
            return head;
            }
```

The struct I use is this

```
typedef struct Nodes {
char    position;
int     i_pos, j_pos;
int     g_distance;
int     h_distance;
int     F_estim;
struct Nodes    *parent;
struct Nodes    *next;
struct Nodes    *previous;

}Nodes_t;
```

Comment: Parent, next, previous, positon, i_pos and j_pos? What sort of "linked list" is this?!

Comment: After three passes of reading, I concluded that the code can be reduced to less than half the original size. Fewer lines == less chance for error == less reading. (as a side effect, the error will come to the surface. In most cases)

Comment: The next, previous work for the "double linked list". The others variables and pointers work for an implementation of A_star I try to make.

Answer (score 3):

You have used an  assignment `=`  instead of a comparison `==` here:

```
if (a->next=NULL){
```

Which will evaluate to `NULL`, which is false, so will go to your `else` clause, where you do

```
head=a->next;
head->previous=NULL;
```

So `head` becomes `NULL`, then you are trying to dereference a `NULL` pointer to get its `previous` member.

- Quick fix:  Add the missing `=` to the first line I quoted.
- Better fix: Refactor your code.  It is too long and has unnecessary bits.  And don't forget to check your equals operations.

Comment: Good catch! I overlooked it (caused by the quest for program structure ...)

Comment: Thanks man, I cannot believe I missed that.. 
I will try to refactor my code also.